# Error when fetch Python NDB with repeated integer property

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an app engine Python NDB Model that looks like this:

```
class Car(ndb.Model)
name=ndb.StringProperty()
tags=ndb.IntegerProperty(repeated=True)
```

when I go to fetch a Car by key I use:

```
car = ndb.Key('Car', long(6079586488025088)).get()
```

when I do this I am seeing:

```
 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/key.py", line 532, in get
    return self.get_async(**ctx_options).get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 325, in get_result
    self.check_success()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 371, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.send(val)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py", line 689, in get
    pbs = entity._to_pb(set_key=False).SerializePartialToString()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3052, in _to_pb
    prop._serialize(self, pb, projection=self._projection)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1365, in _serialize
    values = self._get_base_value_unwrapped_as_list(entity)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1135, in _get_base_value_unwrapped_as_list
    wrapped = self._get_base_value(entity)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1123, in _get_base_value
    return self._apply_to_values(entity, self._opt_call_to_base_type)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1295, in _apply_to_values
    value[:] = map(function, value)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1177, in _opt_call_to_base_type
    value = _BaseValue(self._call_to_base_type(value))
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1198, in _call_to_base_type
    return call(value)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1274, in call
    newvalue = method(self, value)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1536, in _validate
    (value,))
BadValueError: Expected integer, got None
```

if I remove that property from the model definition it returns fine, so I know it's this property. In the datastore it is listed as having a null value for that field. Any idea why this is happening and how to deal with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generally occurs when you first have a single, non-repeated property and then convert it to a repeated property. When you initially do a `put()`, if you have not yet set the property it will fill the value with None. However, if you then turn it into a repeated property, ndb will read this and think you want `[None]`. Because `None` is not a valid IntegerProperty, trying to serialize and `put()` the data will fail.

In your example it fails on a `get()` because after doing a `get()` from the datastore it tries to serialize the data and put it in memcache.

Depending on your situation, you have a couple of options:

1. If you are only running in the devappserver, clear your datastore by running `devappserver.py --clear_datastore`
2. Do a search for all objects with a None value and replace them with the empty list. This might look something like this:

   ```
   for c in Car.query(Car.tags=None):
     c.tags=[]
     c.put()
   ```

   Note that you have to be careful about a few things here. First, make sure that c.tags only is [None] and not [a, b, c, None], just in case. Second, if you have a lot of Cars with no tags, you won't be able to handle fixing them all in the same request. You'll either want to run on a backend, or pass the data on to Tasks for processing.
3. This is pretty similar to #2, but if you have very little data you could use the Datastore viewer and simply resave the entities with tags = None.

Comment: I choose option 2, I do think it's odd that it can't handle the 'None'. Also a quirk I ran into was to try to test this I wanted to get by Key, but found this of course ran me into the original error, but querying by something other than the key didn't cause the same issue and I was able to test a single entry.

Not sure why getting by Key causes the problem, but a query does not given that both return the same object.

Comment: The issue is that get, unlike a query, tries to save the entity to memcache. At this point ndb tries to serialize the entity and fails. You can fix this by turning off memcache until the problem is fixed by calling `ndb.get_context().set_memcache_policy(False)`